# How to initialize a array out of line?

Tags: c++

How to initialize an array, out of the length definition line?

```
int a[5]; //this line fixed, only state the array name and size
a = {1,2,3,4,5};  //error: Array type 'int [5]' is not assignable
a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};//error: expected expression
```

What's the correct way (use one line) to fill `{1,2,3,4,5}` into `a[5]` out of the definition line?

Comment: Can't be done, I'm afraid. Arrays are extremely simple, limited tools. [Is `std::array` an available option?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: You can assign to `std::vector`, but not this way, as it inherits from C which did not have that capability either. Tip: Do it on one line. Do it `const` if it won't change.

Comment: @user4581301, yes.

Comment: An array is NOT an lvalue.

Comment: The correct way would be: `int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};` Though I would probably use: `int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Old-style' arrays in C++ cannot be assigned data *en bloc*, but they can be *initialized* when first declared, as you have pointed out.

However, the [`std::array` container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) provided by the STL *does* allow its data block to be reassigned (with some caveats):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int,5> a;
    // Some code that does someting ...

    a = { 1,2,3,4,5 }; // Now we can ASSIGN one array (a constant) to our variable

    // Show the data ...
    for (auto i : a) std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    a = { 10, 20, 30 }; // Reassign only PART. But note: the rest will be zero-padded
    for (auto i : a) std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, you can use the `a` variable (once you have data in it) in much the same way as with a 'plain' array, such as using the `[]` indexing operator to read/write any of its elements.  Further, you can also copy entire arrays of this type.

Answer (score 2):

> How to initialize an array, out of the length definition line?

Then it can't be an [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) again. (And raw arrays can't be assigned directly, while `std::array` or `std::vector` could.)

(emphasis mine)

> Initialization of a variable provides its initial value **at the time of construction**.

You can use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) (or `std::fill` etc.) to fill the array, e.g.

```
int a[5]; // default initialization
std::iota(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 1); // fill the array as {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```